# How network devices affect TTL

Tags: router, ping, switch, ttl

When I do a ping, I can see the TTL value for each packet. For every router that I insert in between my computer and the router that connects to the internet, the TTL value goes down by one. However, inserting a switch or a hub does not have any effect on the TTL value. Why is that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TTL is part of the IPv4 protocol (on v6 it is called "Hop Limit", as per Steven Monday's comment). Switches and hubs operate on a different layer of the ISO/OSI model (layer 2 as opposed to layer 3 - there do exist so-called layer 3 switches, but I assume you're not asking about them as you include hubs as well).

```
The TTL field is set by the sender of the datagram, 
and reduced by every host on the route to its destination.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

A switch or hub isn't a host on the IP protocol sense - they usually don't have IP addresses. If they do (in the case of switches) they are for management purposes and don't really take part in the actual functioning of the device. Switches work with MAC addresses instead, mapping them to ports and "routing" the packet only in the sense of sending it down the right port (hubs do much less work and send them through all ports instead). They don't inspect or alter the IP payload - you could be using other protocols as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_model

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a very minor nitpick: IPv6 does not have a "Time To Live" header. Instead, it has "Hop Limit", which is equivalent to the IPv4 TTL.

Comment: Didn't know that! Thanks, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @EduardoIvanec What is the difference between TTL and "Hop Limit" (besides the name of course)?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't know of any difference apart from the name. I'm guessing it was changed to make it clear that the original semantic from IPv4 RFCs (using TTL literally as a time field instead of the more common hop count, at least in some cases) is deprecated.

Comment: @Pacerier: allow me to clarify. With IPv4 a router has to decrement the TTL field by at least 1, but may choose to decrement TTL by more than 1. In IPv6 the "hop limit" should always be decreased by 1 as per RFC 2460.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, Time To Live was implemented to prevent **routing**(OSI Layer 3) loops. That is to prevent a packet from hoping forever between the same nodes without ever reaching its destination. So only the nodes that make a **routing** decision for the packet decrease its TTL by one. When TTL reaches zero then the packet is dropped again only by a device making routing decisions.